# OAuth tutorial for non Facebook, Linkedin, Twitter

Tags: iphone, oauth

Does anyone know of an OAuth sample app tutorial that does not deal with Facebook, Twitter etc?

All the samples I can find are bloated with stuff for these sites which for someone trolling through the web trying to learn about this stuff is confusing.

OAuth seems complicated enough but trying to figure out which bits do not apply and which bits do is a minefield...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849 I've found the rfc the easiest to work through.